# Spring Data - MongoDB - JUnit test

Tags: spring, junit, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I would have a question concerning Spring Data - MongoDB and JUnit test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { UserRepository.class, User.class })
public class MyJUnitTest {
```

The UserRepository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    User findByUsername(final String username);
}
```

I get the following Exception:

> Failed to instantiate [... .repository.UserRepository]: Specified class is an interface

My question now would be, how to do it, that UserRepository is instantiate although there is no implementation class because Spring Data does the implementation by its own? If I do not mark USerRepository with @Repository than Spring does not create a bean object

[EDIT]

I have tried the example of the link you posted and it works fine if I run the application over the main- method.
Then I tried to implement a test class but in this case I get the same exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'hello.test.TestClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private hello.CustomerRepository hello.test.TestClass.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

My test class looks like this in src/test/java/hello/test (hello.test is the package):

```
@ComponentScan("hello")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "hello")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { CustomerRepository.class,     Customer.class })
public class TestClass {

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository repository;

@Test
public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("repositoryd: " + repository);
    }
}
```

and my CustomerRepository looks like this (with @Configuration annotation):

```
@Configuration
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);

public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

Actually I don't know which annotations I need in order to get the test running - Maybe you would have another suggestion in order that I can solve this issue.

Comment: Remove the `@Repository` annotation from the `UserRepository` interface.  
Spring Data uses a different mechanism for discovering Spring Data Repository types

Comment: The link to the blog entry is dead...

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Boot `1.5.8.RELEASE`

You can use `@SpringBootTest` to bootstrap all you spring configurations.

Your test will look like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        someRepository.someMethod(...);
        // assertions
    }
}
```

Of course you want to use embedded mongodb for test so add

**`for Maven`**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**`for Gradle`**

```
testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
```

Comment: Really so simple??? But what about `@Autowired` of services and other fields? Is `@SpringBootTest` able to autowire them? (I am using mockito for tests in Spring...)

Comment: What other fields?

Comment: I was thinking about several services and repositories.

Comment: Repositories should not depend on services and for other repositories you can just add like SomeRepository and if spring can find it it will load it.

Answer (score 1):

Your repo `CustomerRepository` doesn't require `@Configuration` or `@Repository` annotations. Spring will do it for you as you extends base Repository classes.

To setup Mongo Repositories you need to extend `ApplicationContext` with the following annotations.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration // create MongoTemplate and MongoOperations
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "hello.test") // Create your repos
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

You also would like to use in-memory database for you unit/integration tests so them won't alter productions database.

To enable it just add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
  <version>1.50.2</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Finally, configure you test class with the `ApplicationContext`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)
public class MyJUnitTest {
    // Test cases ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` you need to point to a configuration class. Neither `UserRepository` nor `User` probably are one I assume.

To get started with both Spring and Spring Data MongoDB fundamentals, be sure to check out [this getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/).

Comment: Hello Oliver, I have tried the example of the link and it works fine - but I don't know how to run my test (I have edit my post above). It would be great if you can help me once agin - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If using junit 5 and you want to start up spring in the most lightweight way possible you will need the following annotations on your IntegrationTest class

```
@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyMongoService.class})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = MyRepository.class)
public class MyMongoIntegrationTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MyMongoService myMongoService; <-- Assuming this injects MyRepository
    
}
```