# Unable to mock MongoTemplate executeQuery using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mockito

I'm looking to mock MongoTemplate, so that the executeQuery function in my service can be actually get called.
This is how my service code block looks like:

```
 this.mongoTemplate.executeQuery(query, collectionName, new DocumentCallbackHandler() {

            @Override
            public void processDocument(Document document) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
                try {
                    // convert to strongly typed object
                  System.out.println("Actual method called");
                    ProductDayData pdd = mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(ProductDayData.class, document);

                    // call copyover
                    backFillOneEvent(pdd, liveContractIds, pddType, toDate, now, timeAtStartOfDay);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("FATAL: backfill - error processing document: {}", document, e);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    LOGGER.error("FATAL: backfill - error processing document: {}", document, t);
                    throw t;
                }
            }

        });
```

In my unit test, this is what I've done:

```
@Mock
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

service = new MyService(mongoTemplate); //mock is set
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(mongoTemplate).executeQuery(Mockito.any(Query.class),Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(DocumentCallbackHandler.class));
```

The doCallRealMethod() apparently doesn't do anything, I expected it to trigger the actual method.

Comment: `@Mock` creates `a bare-bones shell instance`, so it can't call real method... Try to use `@Spy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Spy` instead of `Mock`.

```
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = Mockito.spy(
    //Instance the MongoTemplate, use any test framework
    new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory("mongodb://localhost/test"))
);
// Since it's spy, by default, it will execute real method
//Skipping stub Mockito.doCallRealMethod()....

System.out.println("Real");
mongoTemplate.executeQuery(query, collectionName, new DocumentCallbackHandler() {

        @Override
        public void processDocument(Document document) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
            //Simplified version
            System.out.println("Actual method called:" + document.toJson());
        }

    });
System.out.println("End Real");

//Now call fake `executeQuery`
Mockito.doNothing().when(mongoTemplate).executeQuery(Mockito.any(Query.class), Mockito.any(String.class),
            Mockito.any(DocumentCallbackHandler.class));
System.out.println("Mock");
mongoTemplate.executeQuery(query, collectionName, new DocumentCallbackHandler() {

        @Override
        public void processDocument(Document document) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
            //Simplified version
            System.out.println("Actual method called:" + document.toJson());
        }

});
System.out.println("End Mock");

//Now we "enable" real method call  
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(mongoTemplate).executeQuery(Mockito.any(Query.class), Mockito.any(String.class),
        Mockito.any(DocumentCallbackHandler.class));
System.out.println("Real 2");
mongoTemplate.executeQuery(query, collectionName, new DocumentCallbackHandler() {

    @Override
    public void processDocument(Document document) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
        System.out.println("Actual method called:" + document.toJson());
    }

});
System.out.println("End Real 2");
```

--Output---

```
Real
//MongoDB traces...
Actual method called:{...}
Actual method called:{...}
...
End Real
Mock
End Mock
Real 2
//MongoDB traces...
Actual method called:{...}
Actual method called:{...}
...
End Real 2
```

Links: [`@Mock` vs `@Spy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052984/what-is-the-difference-between-mocking-and-spying-when-using-mockito)

Comment: I had one question - The Mockito.spy(
    //Instance the MongoTemplate, use any test framework
    new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory("mongodb://localhost/test"))
); doesn't work in the CI/CD setup. Does this mean we have to have a local Mongo running  on the build server?

Comment: @rishabh No. You can use `Fongo` / [flapdoodle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587430/spring-data-mongodb-junit-test)