# Junit5 is not mocking MongoTemplate after updating to Java 11

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mocking, junit5

After updating to Spring Boot 2.6.8 with Java v11 and using Junit5 I'm not able to Mock anymore `MongoTemplate`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RepositoryImpl.class})
class RepositoryImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryImpl repositoryImpl;

    @MockBean
    private MongoTemplate db;
    

   ...

}
```

I get the following error
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.`

as per dependency I have in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure you only updated the Java version and not also the Spring Boot version? What were the previous versions?

Comment: Hi @johanneslink, yes I updated spring boot as well

Comment: Maybe the following answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66599766/32352